# How to define a field with a parameterized List using Javassist

Tags: java, javassist

How can I define a parameterized List field using Javassist?  I have tried the following code which does not complain with an unparameterized List class, but causes a CannotCompileException when given a parameter.

```
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    pool.importPackage("java.util.List");
    CtClass cc = pool.makeClass("Test");
    CtField f = CtField.make("public List<String> p;", cc);
    // throws javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] syntax error near "lic List<String> p;"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess the language compliance level of the compiler javassist is using internally is set to Java 1.4, which would explain why it doesn't understand generics (they were introduced in 1.4)

Comment: From the tutorial (http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial3.html#generics) "The lower-level API of Javassist fully supports generics introduced by Java 5. On the other hand, the higher-level API such as CtClass does not directly support generics."